# What is the difference between the metric space and the normed vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm already know that these two spaces differ in directionality, and I have found two examples.

The first example is that in a metric space, the closure of an open ball is not always a closed ball. However, this seems to be a difference based on the choice of the set and the given metric.

The second example is from the following exercise:

> In every complete normed vector space V, if there exists a sequence of non-empty closed balls $\overline{\{B_{\delta_n}(x_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}\}}$ such that for every $i=1,2,\ldots$ $\overline{B_{\delta_i}(x_i)}\supset \overline{B_{\delta_{i+1}}(x_{i+1})}$ and $\delta_{i}>\delta_{i+1}>\cdots>0.$ then B=$\bigcap^\infty_{n=1}\overline{B_{\delta_n}(x_n)}$ is non-empty. this property may not hold when transforming the normed linear space into a metric space.

I attempted to solve the problem, but it relied on completeness.-it was solved using the fact that it is complete and utilizing Cauchy sequences.-

I would like to understand the difference between a normed vector space and a metric space without relying on completeness. What is the fundamental distinction between these two spaces?

Furthermore, if we remove the completeness condition from the second example, would it still hold true? And what would be the approach to solving it without completeness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every normed vector space is a metric space, but not the other way round. There are several ways to define "crazy" metrics such as the French Metro Metric, which are not very intuitive and also the underlying set does not have to be a vector space but can be just a set as well.

Regarding you second question, it is not true that an intersection of closed balls has to be non-empty in the non-complete case, this is even true in the one-dimensional case, consider $\mathbb{Q}$ with the standard metric and
\begin{align}
B_i = \{ x \in \mathbb{Q} \ | \ |x-a_i| \leq \frac{1}{i} \}
\end{align}
for $a_i$ a sequence converging to $\sqrt 2$ (or your favorite irrational number).

Comment: Then, can I understand that apart from the peculiar distance function, there is no difference between the two spaces?

Comment: If your underlying "space" is a vector space, and the metric is induced from a norm then yes, you can consider them as morally the same object. I just edited my answer slightly to make the example that I gave a bit more exact.